# How to resolve the syntax error in sql query

Tags: mysql, ddl

I am getting error for the query:

```
ALTER TABLE `cms_users` ADD `show_on_web` TINYINT(4)  NOT NULL  DEFAULT '1';
```

And i am getting error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '  NOT NULL  DEFAULT '1'' at line 1

I am not sure what the error is.

To verify the Query - http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Add Column `show_on_web` ?

Comment: Not sure if it is related to your particular issue, but shouldn't you use `DEFAULT 1;` instead of `DEFAULT '1';`, as your column is a TINYINT , and not a VARCHAR ?

Comment: The Type of the Column is TinyInt and you set default as character-type.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - you need to add column and also default will be 1 not '1' because your data type is tinyint

```
ALTER TABLE `cms_users` 
ADD column `show_on_web` TINYINT(4)  NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
```

Comment: What is the difference between your code and OP's code ?

Comment: add 'column' - I've added column there @Pac0

Comment: @AjuJohn, - check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=85630ec05d18d80f9244d6e61615e0cd - it should work definiely

Comment: Checked at https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check, http://sqlfiddle.com, https://dbfiddle.uk. Only worked with https://dbfiddle. I am not sure why!

Answer (score 0):

As fa06 posted, you are missing `COLUMN` after the `ADD`.

Also, there is a type mismatch with your DEFAULT clause (quotes imply VARCHAR and not TINYINT).

Try this :

```
ALTER TABLE `cms_users` ADD COLUMN `show_on_web` TINYINT(4)  NOT NULL  DEFAULT 1;
```

PS : For some reason, SQLFiddle does not work for me today. However, I juste tried the following :

```
CREATE TABLE cms_users (
    id INT
    );

ALTER TABLE `cms_users` ADD COLUMN `show_on_web` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;
```

on https://paiza.io/en/languages/mysql , and it shows no compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
ALTER TABLE `cms_users` ADD COLUMN `show_on_web` TINYINT(4)  NOT NULL  DEFAULT 1;
```

I've added a COLUMN word and removed quotes of default value.

Because it's TINYINT - Integer, you need to use 1 instead of '1'.
Because '1' is string.

Comment: Its `Add Column`